# ¿como programo un jbutton que remplaze los datos de un public static ? en java

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica

Estos son los datos que quiero remplazar

```
    public static String modelo0 = "Aviator";
    public static double precio0 = 124.9;
    public static double ancho0 = 63.5;
    public static double alto0 = 30.9;  
    public static double fondo0 = 29.2;
```

lo que quiero es que al poner un numero en la siguiente casilla y pulsar el jbutton de grabar, se remplaze el valor de esos datos.

![Gui del botton]([image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí])

Comment: los datos estáticos no los puedes cambiar, lo que sí puedes cambiar, es el texto de tus cuadros de texto. necesitas que sean estáticos?

Comment: recien estoy aprendiendo de java pero encontre una manera de llamar los datos estaticos fuera de un dato estatico, te lo muestro con un  ejemplo:     Menu.modelo0, estas seguro que no se pueden remplazar esos datos al poner un dato en las casilla y luego darle a grabar?

Comment: me lo dejaron de trabajo y ya llevo varias amanecidas pero nose como xd

Comment: usa setText() para cambiar el valor de ese campo y cambia el valor de la variable

Comment: puedes cambiar el dato de la casilla, poque pues pertenece a ella, pero un valor estático no puedes cambiarlo, ese es el chiste de que sea estático

Comment: Si la variable estática es pública todos acceden a la misma variable (todos los objetos desde fuera) y todos modifican la misma variable. Sin embargo cuando no pueden ser modificados posterior a su creación o asignación usan la palabra reservada Final

Comment: Quieres reemplazar los valores del TextField a los valores Static, o quieres poner los valores static a los TextField?

Comment: quiero que el valor que le ponga al textfield remplaze al static

Comment: No es posible cambiar un valor Static, como mencionaban anteriormente, puedes cambiar el valor de una variable partiendo de tu  static y modificarlo al gusto, pero el static no puede ser cambiado, que fue exactamente lo que pidieron que hicieras con el static?

Comment: Al seleccionar esta opción del menú se mostrará la caja de diálogo de la Figura 3(la imagen que pase)
en la que se podrá elegir un modelo de maleta y modificar sus datos.
Considere que:
• Cuando la caja diálogo se haga visible deberán verse inmediatamente los datos de
la primera maleta.
• Al seleccionar un modelo de maleta se mostrarán inmediatamente sus datos en
JTextField editables en los que podrán hacerse modificaciones.
• Al pulsar el botón Guardar se guardarán los cambios efectuados y se cerrará la caja
de diálogo.
• Al pulsar el botón Cerrar se cerrará la caja de diálogo.

Comment: eso es lo que me dijieron que haga y junto con eso me pasaron los datos del public static, diciendo>> Considere la siguiente declaración mínima de variables globales que almacenarán los datos de cada maleta:

Comment: en fin, si es mucho trabajo, igual gracias por todas sus respuestas <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claro que se puede capturar los datos de JTextField y guardarlos en cualquier variable así sea `Static` con tal que no sea `Final` debido a que estos tipos no pueden ser modificados; la forma de capturar los datos es:

```
public static String modelo0 = "Aviator";
public static double precio0 = 124.9;
public static double ancho0 = 63.5;
public static double alto0 = 30.9;  
public static double fondo0 = 29.2;

//Nos vamos el evento del boton 
private void btn_GrabarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
        //Obtenemos el valor del combobox, realizando un cast a String                                          
        modelo0=(String) cmb_Modelo.getSelectedItem(); 
        /*
        Obtenemos el valor de un JTextField y realizamos un parse
        debido a que la caja de texto retorna un valor de tipo String  
        */     
        precio0=Double.parseDouble(txt_Precio.getText());        

        //Mostramos los nuevos valores que almacenan nuestras variables
        System.out.println("NOmbre del nuevo modelo:"+modelo0);
        System.out.println("Valor nuevo del precio: "+precio0);
        
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias eso me sirvio